# previous button not working Android

Tags: android

I am working through an exercise in the Big Nerd Ranch book. The exercise is to add a previous button to an Android app. I have everything set up, it is drawn in the build, but does not react to press. What i tried to do was mirror the 'next' button the book describes but decrement the counter rancher than increment.... any thoughts?

```
});

    mPrevButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
             mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex-1) % mQuestionBank.length;
             mIsCheater = false;
             updateQuestion();
         }
    });
```

the 'next' that does work:

```
mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
             mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex+1) % mQuestionBank.length;
             mIsCheater = false;
             updateQuestion();
         }
    });

private void updateQuestion(){
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}
```

Comment: You can have a negative value in mCurrentIndex and a IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown in mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding this instead of your line.

```
mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + mQuestionBank.length - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
```